# Laravel 8 Class 'Database\Seeders\App\Models\Admin' not found

Tags: php, laravel, web, laravel-8

I'm currently learning on Database Seeding in Laravel 8. When runnning the seed I got an error message

> Class 'Database\Seeders\App\Models\Admin' not found

First I created migration database file called **Admin.php** in **App\Models** and I put these codes

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Notification\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
//use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    protected $guard = 'admin';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'type','email','password','image','status','created_at','updated_at',
    ];
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

After that I created a seeder called **AdminsTableSeeder.php** and put these codes

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use DB;

class AdminsTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('admins')->delete();
        $adminRecords = [
            [
                'id'=>1, 
                'name'=>'admin', 
                'type'=>'admin',
                'email'=>'admin@admin.com',
                'password'=>'',
                'image'=>'',
                'status'=>1,
            ],
        ];
        foreach ($adminRecords as $key => $record){
            App\Models\Admin::create($record);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally on **DatabaseSeeder.php** I put these codes to call **AdminsTableSeeder**

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $this->call(AdminsTableSeeder::class);

    }
}
```

After I'm done with all of those, I did composer du and trying to run the seed command but I got the error message.

**EDIT**
I already tried to modify the code from

```
foreach ($adminRecords as $key => $record){
            App\Models\Admin::create($record);
        }
```

to

```
foreach ($adminRecords as $key => $record){
            \App\Models\Admin::create($record);
        }
```

But I stil got the error message like

> Seeding: Database\Seeders\AdminsTableSeeder
> PHP Fatal error:  Trait 'Illuminate\Notification\Notifiable' not found in C:\xam
> pp\htdocs\tobacon_web\app\Models\Admin.php on line 11

> Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError

> Trait 'Illuminate\Notification\Notifiable' not found

Comment: `App\Models\Admin::create($record);` to `\App\Models\Admin::create($record);`

Comment: hey I already tried it before but it still showing the error message, you can check on my post I already edited and explained the problem

Comment: `use Illuminate\Notification\Notifiable;` to `use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;` fix this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your **AdminsTableSeeder.php** file, change the line:

```php
App\Models\Admin::create($record);
```

to

```php
\App\Models\Admin::create($record);
```

or add a use statement as `use App\Models\Admin` at the top of your file and edit your code to just `Admin::create($record)`.

Comment: Hey, I already tried to modify the code but I think another problem showing up. You can see my edited post, I already explained there after I modify my code the error saying "Trait 'Illuminate\Notification\Notifiable' not found"

Comment: The `Notifiable` trait is found in `Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable`. You are trying to use it from `Illuminate\Notification\Notifiable`. That's why you are getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

this error may come if you copied you User.php in order to create your Admin.php Model.

to correct this check

Admin.php

```
//change 

class User extends Authenticatable


//to 

class Admin extends Authenticatable
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the [help]. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.